# Why do IIS application pools need to be recycled?

Tags: iis, application-pool

Application pools in IIS are recycled very frequently and I can't figure out why. I remember reading about a possible issue in IIS6 that meant you were forced to recycle but a quick search now turns up empty. On IIS6 or 7 you can turn off the idle time, duration and specific time recycle options so no problems there.

So why does every .net site recycle the application pool? If a site didn't have any memory leaks could you set up a site that never needed to recycle?

Also failing this, what would be the best way to ensure background tasks are called, is there any auto restart modules for IIS or should an external service be used to make those calls?

It sounds like it is possible to do if you really wanted/needed to?

Comment: Even if you have no memory leaks, if you've got any allocations in the LOH, you may end up with fragmentation.

Comment: That's still something you can fix, I want to know if you can do it, not just what can go wrong. Plus the end of the LOH would be empty wouldn't it?

Comment: I think you seriously underestimate the amount of work required to ensure that there are *no* resource leaks.

Comment: Would it not be better though in most cases to try and fix resource leaks before saying it's too hard.

Comment: You can now compact the LOH in .net 4.5

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Websites are intended to keep running (albeit in a stateless nature). There are a myriad of reasons why app pool recycling can be beneficial to the hosting platform to ensure both the website and the server run at optimum. These include (but not limited to) dynamically compiled assemblies remaining in the appdomain, use of session caching (with no guarantee of cleanup), other websites running amok and resources getting consumed over time etc. An app pool can typically serve more than one website, so app pool recycling can be beneficial to ensure everything runs smoothly.

Besides the initial boot when the app fires up again, the effect should be minimal. Http.sys holds onto requests while a new worker process is started so no requests should be dropped.

Comment: I hope you meant "albeit in a tasteless nature", but I suspect you were aiming for stateless?

Comment: Well the effect should be minimal, but your in-proc session state is gone.

Answer (score 10):

From https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/why-is-the-iis-default-app-pool-recycle-set-to-1740-minutes

> You may ask whether a fixed recycle is even needed. A daily recycle is
>   just a band-aid to freshen IIS in case there is a slight memory leak
>   or anything else that slowly creeps into the worker process. In theory
>   you don’t need a daily recycle unless you have a known problem. I used
>   to recommend that you turn it off completely if you don’t need it.
>   However, I’m leaning more today towards setting it to recycle once per
>   day at an off-peak time as a proactive measure.
>
> My reason is that, first, your site should be able to survive a
>   recycle without too much impact, so recycling daily shouldn’t be a
>   concern. Secondly, I’ve found that even well behaving app pools can
>   eventually have something sneak in over time that impacts the app
>   pool. I’ve seen issues from traffic patterns that cause excessive
>   caching or something odd in the application, and I’ve seen the very
>   rare IIS bug (rare indeed!) that isn’t a problem if recycled daily. Is
>   it a band-aid? Possibly, but if a daily recycle keeps a non-critical
>   issue from bubbling to the top then I believe that it’s a good
>   proactive measure to save a lot of troubleshooting effort on something
>   that probably isn’t important to troubleshoot. However, if you think
>   you have a real issue that is being suppressed by recycling then, by
>   all means, turn off the auto-recycling so that you can track down and
>   resolve your issue. There’s no black and white answer. Only you can
>   make the best decision for your environment.

There's a lot more useful/interesting info for someone relatively unlearned in the IIS world (like me), I recommend you read it.